# NodeJs Express send 403 and render

Tags: node.js, express

How can I send a error 403 and render a page with 'you have no rights to visited this page' message?

I have now this:

```
res.send(403,"You do not have rights to visit this page");
```

but I want to render a HTML page instead a basic text

```
res.render('no-rights', {title: 'You have no rights to visit this page', text: 'You are not allowed to visited this page. Maybe you are not logged in?'});
```

with a 403 status.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status

```
res.status(403);
res.render();
```

Or in one line

```
res.status(403).render();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the response is for an API call, you can do it:

```
res.status(403).json({})
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) page of Express you can set the status first and then render the page.

```
  res.status(500);
  res.render('error', { error: err });
```

similarly I would create a page that could inform the user about the 4xx (client error) and 5xx (server error) errors in a similar way by passing the status code and the title as parameters.